# Encoding the categorical columna make data too sparse

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, one-hot-encoding

I have got a couple of questions.

1. if data set has some categorical
   Varibles and it needs one hot encoding then sometimes as there are so many categories within each columns, one hot encoding increases the total number of columns to 200 or more. How do i deal with this?
2. what is a good number for total columns that go into model training , like are 50 columns or 20 columns or is it totally dependent on the dataset.

Answer (score -1):

Generally it's good to have a lot of examples. This amount of column is not to much.

I recommend instead to focus on:

1. Deletion missing or not relevant data which may influence to wrong output after all transformations.
2. Provide significant number of records which magnify your learning effect.

Comment: Okay, I get that. Thanks man

Comment: One master made minus to this post but even not wrote why.